# Good Antivirus / Malware / Ransomware with no ads, free or paid

Tags: windows, windows-10, antivirus, malware

I am currently using AVG paid on Windows 10 (Multiple Device Sub). I am tired of constantly getting hit with ads to buy their other services! Is there a good antivirus, free or paid, that offers multiple device coverage that won't ask/trick me to buy other products. AVG doesn't even offer an option to disable this. I have searched, but without having to download every AV I come across, I have not found a good answer. Also, as anyone with any level of PC expertise will know, downloading multiple AVs even after uninstalls can wreak havoc on a system. Any thing helps.

Comment: I rely on Windows Defender, and only for realtime protection. Personally I feel like everything else is a nuisance. I remember clamav was an open source option, but as I said, I'm tired of AVs.

Comment: As for removal - check out [Bulk Crap Uninstaller](https://www.bcuninstaller.com/), I found this invaluable in cleaning up after carp-installs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best antivirus is [Kaspersky](https://www.kaspersky.com/)'s one. I recommend it definitely because of protection. Any other antiviruses cant protect PC as it can. I have tried every one of them through many years. It never disappointed me. Best for recognizing virus malware etc. as true threat. It has free and paid versions both. If you prefer to use paid version you can definitely use [Kaspersky Internet Security](https://kaspersky.com/internet-security). So you dont have to use OS firewall or Windows Defender like tools for additional security. It has total security tools for extra needs. Also you can try it with trial version.

Comment: Thank you! I tried so many also. I was leaning towards Kapersky but wanted to get input before I paid for it. I made that mistake with AVG and I just ended up paying for ads.

Answer (score 2):

I am happy with [ESET NOD32 Antivirus](https://www.eset.com/int/home/antivirus/) for more than 5 years now. I am using it because of exactly the same requirement: it shall do its work as long as I pay - and nothing else.

This is especially required for my two children, since they can't deal with these messages and I told them to inform me whenever something pops up they don't know.

Comment: Thank you. They are cheaper that AVG. I will use the free trial after AVG uninstall and see how it does.